# swift 2.0 NSDecimalNumber possible discrepency converting to long

Tags: ios, swift, numeric-conversion

I can't make heads or tails of this.  I am using NSDecimalNumber to truncate 
the fractional portion from a string.  This works in most cases, but not apparently in the case of infinite decimals (or just too many).  Here is an example:

```
print(NSDecimalNumber(string: "49.81666666666666666").longLongValue)
print(NSDecimalNumber(string: "49.816666666666666666").longLongValue)
print(NSDecimalNumber(string: "49.8166666666666666666").longLongValue)
```

The first line prints 49, the second -5, and the last one 0.  I know I can use the rounding function to do the same thing, and that is what I will probably use instead, but doesn't this seem odd?  I know it isn't just converting the float bit pattern into a long or else the results would be completely different.

Comment: I'd file a bug with Apple on this. I just experimented with the same strings using Objective-C and saw lots of strange results (on a 5th gen iPod touch with iOS 9.2). `intValue` worked but `integerValue` didn't. `longValue` and `longLongValue` didn't work. `doubleValue` worked.

Comment: Go ahead and [file that bug](http://bugreport.apple.com), but if your main objective is converting strings to numbers, you'd probably do better to use [`NSNumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/index.html) anyway.